# how to re-install deleted packages from sdk manager of android studio?

Tags: android, sdk

I mistakenly deleted some packages from sdk manager of android studio.
dear guys please help me:
how to re-install deleted packages from sdk manager of android studio?

Comment: Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I'm pretty sure you can patch your install with the packages from the SDK download: [https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)